# How to check if in a list of Objects with two properties, all Objects with one equal property also have the same other property?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `Product`s `List<Product> productList`, where:

```
public class Product
{
     int ProductId { get; set; }
     decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

How do I check if in this `productList` all `Product`s with the `ProductId` also have the same `Price`?

I found that this works:

```
bool result = productCheckList.GroupBy(p => p.ProductId).Any(gr => 
                     gr.Distinct().ToList().Count > 1)`;
```

But I also want to find out if one is not similar, *which* ones are not.

So when I have a List like this:

```
var list = new List<Product>
list.Add(new Product { ProductId = 1, Price = 2m }
list.Add(new Product { ProductId = 1, Price = 1m }
```

I want the method to return false, and show ProductId = 1.

Comment: Well, does it? Work I mean?

Comment: I'll check. Already have some unit tests. :-)

Comment: Hmm, I also need to find out which ProductId is double. That makes it bit more difficult.

Comment: Can you describe what kind of answer/result you want from your code in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The groups contains the products, not the prices for the products, so you would need to get the prices out:

```
bool result =
  productCheckList.GroupBy(p => p.ProductId)
  .Any(gr => gr.Select(pr => pr.Price).Distinct().Count() > 1);
```

To get the product groups where the prices differs:

```
List<IGrouping<int, Product>> result =
  productCheckList.GroupBy(p => p.ProductId)
  .Where(gr => gr.Select(pr => pr.Price).Distinct().Count() > 1)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks!! And how to access the prices in the result? `igr.ElementAt(1).Price` works. :-)

Comment: @user2609980: The result is a list of groups, and each group has a key that is the product id, and the group is a collection of the products in the group. If you for example use `ToList` on one of the groups, you get a `List<Product>`.